# How to reach controls inside material design card wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wrap panel and I am adding this card in to wrap panel during drag & drop pdf files to wrap panel. Card will have PDF capture pic, name, size etc. I need to reach controls inside the card to assign pdf capture pic. and other data of pdf file. How can I do that?

And also I am naming card to delete not all of them only selected one.

Also I am open new ideas about listing all dragged and dropped files in wrap panel.

Thanks.

```
<materialDesign:Card x:Key="PDFThumbnail" x:Name="PDFThumbnail" 
 Margin="3,3,0,0" Width="200">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="140" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image      
      Height="140"
      Width="196"
      Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                <StackPanel
      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
      Grid.Row="2"
      Orientation="Horizontal"
      Margin="8">
                    <Button
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}"
        Width="30"
        Padding="2 0 2 0"
        materialDesign:RippleAssist.IsCentered="True">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon
          Kind="Delete" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
```

Comment: Where and when do you need to "reach" the controls in the `Card`?

Comment: During dropping pdf files I will get data of them such as file size, capture Pic, name etc. And specify all data to new card which will show the pdf file and will be added I to wrappanel.

Comment: Please narrow down your issue. What specific control in the `Card` do you want a reference to and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I need to reach the Image to set pdf capture pic to image as image source to show in card. and also need to reach the button to give specific data like id or something to know which pdf file I am deleting.

Comment: The problem is you are probably trying to build the `materialDesign:Card` and sub-elements programmatically, rather than using data binding or MVVM. Due to the structured nature of XAML, it can be difficult to do this programmatically. Rather, if your "model" object has the image, title, and other properties, it is preferable to do: `<Image Source={Binding ImageSource}" ...` where ImageSource is the reference to a BitmapImage. You should research MVVM for WPF for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the `Content` of the `Card` to `Grid` (or `Panel`), you could iterate through its `Children` property and find references to all controls in it:

```
Card card = Resources["PDFThumbnail"] as Card;
Panel panel = card?.Content as Panel;
Image image = panel?.Children.OfType<Image>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Might want to use some `?.` there, otherwise this code will be quite fragile should the hierarchy ever change

Comment: @David: Sure but I omitted all kind of error handling for brevity.